# State is being resetted due to incorrect load function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm new to react-redux and have some trouble persisting the state, mainly problem with loading the state from localstorage. I can save data to localstorage with no problem, however the data inside redux dev tools resets on refresh. The data in localstorage is as it should be.
I speculate that the loadstate function is not working properly, thus not correctly fetching data from localstorage.

The reason for using (key, data) rather than (state) is that i don't get the error "objects are not valid as a react child", but it should work as good as using (state).

My localstorage.js

```
export const saveState = (key, data) => {
  try {
    const serialized = JSON.stringify(data);
    localStorage.setItem(key, serialized);
  } catch (err) {
    // Ignore errors.
  }
}

 export const loadState = () => {
  try {
    const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state');
    if (serializedState === null) {
      return undefined;
      
    }
    return JSON.parse(serializedState);
  } catch (err) {
    return undefined;
  }
};
```

my subscribe method:

```
 store.subscribe(() => {
    const state = store.getState();
    Object.keys(state).forEach( 
     key => {saveState(key, state[key])}
    )
 })
```

My store class:

```
import allReducers from './reducers'
import {createStore} from 'redux';
import { loadState } from './localStorage';

export const store = createStore(allReducers, loadState(), window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__());
```

Answer (score 0):

It’s because you are trying to get from storage entire state but you are saving it by keys that’s why loadState is not returning state. Try something like this

```
store.subscribe(() => {
    const state = store.getState();
    saveState('state', state);
});
```